# How to identify strong and low performers

Tags: correlation, model-evaluation

Scenario:
Our leadership team want to identify deskside technicians that are under-performing so we can provide them additional training and support. I’d like to take data points, do some math and have each technician end up with a “score” so we can see how they rank in effectiveness so we can help those at the bottom.

Difficulties:
-   How do we identify these individual accurately and fairly using data?

Types of data we could use (and caveats):

1. Student count in district (more students means larger district, which means more tech that can break and result in tickets)
2. Number (total or average) of support tickets completed per tech – Caveat: We support 18 school districts and not all of them have the same quantity of tickets so some techs may do 30 a day because their volume is higher and some may do 15 because that’s all they get. How do I weight this fairly?
3. Number (total or average) of tickets that have breached our SLA (eg. if the ticket priority demands that it is done in 3 days, how many took > 3 days to complete, thus not satisfying our SLA)
4. Number (total or average) of tickets per site
5. Number (total or average) tickets across all sites
6. % of total (across all sites) tickets each tech closes
7. Average time to close (timestamp of creation minus timestamp of close = duration open)
8. Rankings of each of these compared to other techs
9. There may be other data points so if you have ideas I can tell you if we have a data point, but these are the ones off the top of my head

Initial thoughts:
Important metrics would be: % tickets breached SLA, total tickets completed (weighted to compensate for high/low ticket volumes), and average time to close

I’m thinking possibly:

1. A= Create a fair process for weighting the total tickets completed to compensate for high/low ticket volumes… this just needs to be weighted fairly
2. B= Create a score for time to close, possibly using some percentage +/- the mean across all techs (maybe measured in days?)… we want this to be low
3. C= Create a score for % of tickets breached SLA, possibly using some percentage +/- the mean across all techs… we want this to be low
4. Final score = (B*C)/A  ?

If so, how do I properly get to A, B & C?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodhart%27s_law

Comment: Thanks Stephan. We talked about this as a leadership team (though we didn't know it as Goodhart's law, just the concept in general) and recognize that this is a possibility.  Since we're not using it for punitive purposes, just for finding techs that might need additional help (be it training or that they're overwhelmed with tickets and need a teammate to distribute the load), we likely won't be disclosing the metrics we're using so we're hoping this happens less.

Comment: This is not a statistical question, but a question regarding management. I completely side with Stephan: If you make "tickets completed" the main outcome without ensuring that this is synonymous to "source of problem solved & customer satisfied" you will reward ticket-pushers, not good technicians.

Comment: Agreed. That's why I want to find a better solution than # completed.  One data point I forgot to mention is that we send customer service surveys for each closed ticket, which is essentially a single question Y/N - "were you satisfied with the quality of support you received for this issue?" We can also have that be part of the score.

I want to emphasize that we will not be using this for punitive purposes, not even for annual reviews. Our mgmt culture is VERY heavy on coaching & helping our staff so our staff won't even know they're being evaluated.... just helping the lower performers.

Comment: I do thank everyone that's looked at the scenario and responded. I appreciate the feedback and ideas. We have around 40 techs at 18 schools across 6 counties, each of which are unique in their own ways. We're trying to improve our customer service (which is actually already very good). We have training funds and are trying to find the best (lowest performing) techs to use those training funds on. We get lots of anecdotal data about who needs help and who doesn't, with a lot of conflicting anecdotes. If we can, we'd like use data to help drive those decisions.  Thanks again to everyone helping!